# How to color only one type of character in a text using terminal?

Tags: command-line

I want to color only the symbol & in a text file named test.txt

Comment: The `txt` files are plain text files and not capable of coloring any character... so you can't do this.

Comment: @Ravexina not even in vim?

Comment: @JenaAlissa you can use `vim`'s syntax highlighting to change the way text appears while you're editing it, but vim syntax highlighting won't change the file itself. Text files can't store formatting.  Can you be more explicit about what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want to display the contents of your text file in a terminal and highlight all `&` characters in that output.

The file `test.txt` could look like this:

```
Apples & Bananas
Strawberries & Raspberries
Cookies & Chocolate & Ice Cream
Pizza

Pineapples
```

You can then use `grep` to color all portions of the file that match a given pattern:

```
grep -E '^|&' test.txt
```

[image: colored output]

What this command does is to match the extended (`-E` enables that, allowing us to use `|` in the pattern) regular expression `^|&` against every line of the input file `test.txt`, printing every line containing a match with the actually matching part highlighted in red.

We use the pattern `^|&` to match either the beginning of a line (`^`) or the literal  ampersand character (`&`). The first part is needed to include all lines in the output, not only those which contain ampersands.

Note: color is implicitly enabled, because by default on Ubuntu, `grep` is aliased to `grep --color=auto`, which turns on colored highlighting if the output goes to a terminal (and not e.g. into a pipe or a file). If you do not have this alias, you'd have to add the `--color=auto` or `--color=always` argument to `grep` yourself.